# Rails communicating with jquery through erb

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm querying Rails for whether a record exists through a has many through relationship in erb:

```
<% if @hack.serials %>
```

Ultimately if a 'serial' does not exist within the '@hack' I want to add 'display: none' to a div's class through jquery.

Is there a pattern for communicating between rails and jquery through erb in this way?

**Edit**

The idea here is that if there's no data, than the I don't want the tabs and its content to show up.  And until the 'hack' is edited and the page is reloaded the div "chart-table" will not have data, so will not need to become visible.

```
<div class = "chart-table" 
  <% if @hack.serials %>
    <%= raw 'style="display:block"' %>
  <% end %>>
<!-- TABS -->
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Chart</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Last 5 Table</a></li>
  </ul>
<!-- CHART -->
<div id="tabs-1">
  <div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px"></div>
</div>
<!-- TABLE -->
<div id="tabs-2">
  <table class = "table-condensed">
    <%= @hack.id %>
    <% @hack.serials.each do |s| %>  
    <tr>
       <th>Series Title</th>
        <th>Series Name</th>
        <th>Series Id</th>
      <% s.observations.sort{|a,b| a.id <=> b.id}.last(5).each do |o| %>
        <th><%= o.date %></th>
      <% end %>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to s.title, [@hack, s] %></td>
      <td><%= s.series_name %></td>
      <td><%= s.id %></td>
    <% s.observations.sort{|a,b| a.id <=> b.id}.last(5).each do |o| %>
      <% if s.units_short == 'Mil. of $' %>
        <td><%= number_to_currency(convertMtoBHack(o.value), :precision => 0) %></td>
        <% else %>
          <td><%= number_to_currency(o.value, :precision => 0) %></td>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><%= s.frequency_short %></td>
      <td><%= s.units_short %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you feel the need to do this via jQuery.

Why not write the div's style attribute directly?

```
<div <%= @hack.serials ? 'style="display:none"' : '' %>>
```

Comment: Many thanks...I did need to add raw to take '<div class = "chart-table" style=&quot;display:none&quot;>'.  So, <div <%= raw @hack.serials ? 'style="display:none"' : '' %>> worked great.

Comment: After checking I actually only tested it on the hack that didn't have a serial.  When I tested it on a hack that did have a serial, display was still set to none. I did need to add raw to take '<div class = "chart-table" style=&quot;display:none&quot;>'.  So, <div <%= raw hack.serials ? 'style="display:none"' : '' %>> worked but didn't differentiate whether it had a hack or not.

Comment: What if you need to write another inline style on that element?  In other words, this solution does not scale well.

Comment: @tagCincy, if there is no data, then the <div> and everything it contains will not be shown and will not be turned back on during the life of the page.  What I'm trying to prevent is having a bunch of stuff that is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
<script>
    <% unless @hack.serials.map(&:name).include? "My Serial" %>
        $('#my_serial_id').css('display', 'none');
    <% end %>
</script>
```

If you are looking for the serial which name is "My Serial" and do not find it, then stop displaying the corresponding div.

Rails code is executed on the server side and then rendered to the client which executes the javascript. So you can pass anything you want from Rails to javascript.

FIY passing javascript to Rails would require other tricks and magic stuff (like ajax for instance).

Comment: I don't think the unless makes any difference since the $('#my_serial_id').css('display', 'none'); will be rendered regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Will this div be displayed later after some ajax class (prior the DOM reloading)?  If not, I would question whether you should even write it.

I would be wary of Mark Hollands answer because, although it works, it could present problems if you have any future UI changes on that element.  If you need to write the element, I would stick to a straight conditional with and put the "static" code in a partial:

```
<% if @hack.serials %>
  <div>
    <%= render 'something' %>
  </div>
<% else %>
  <div style='display:none'>
    <%= render 'something' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: First, nothing will change after the page is loaded. Although appreciated Mark's answer doesn't work from the standpoint of changing whether @hack.serials is an empty array or has data in it.  I've edited my original question to include the code in question.

Comment: @JohnGalt Could you just wrap all of that code in an unless condition?
`<% unless @hack.serials.nil? %>`
If it doesn't need to be displayed prior to the page reloading, then why write it?

Answer (score 0):

The good folks over at Rails Hotline helped me to the answer.

```
<% if @hack.serials.present? %>
  <div class = "chart-table">
    <!-- TABS -->
    <div id="tabs">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Chart</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Last 5 Table</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

If "empty" @hack.serials returns an empty array but returns true.  Using @hack.serials.present? returns false if it's an empty array which is the behavior I was looking for.